# How can i count the average time of creation and update time?

Tags: php, time, pdo

I have the following code and want to count the average time when i 
submit the spot object im use the date() function.

```
$query3 =$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `ks`.`spots`  WHERE solved=:solved;");
$query3->bindParam(':solved', $not_solved, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query3->execute();
$num_of_solved1 = $query3->rowCount();
$results = $query3->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

foreach( $results as $row ) {

    //$temp_created_at =        $row['created_at'];
    //$temp_updated_at =        $row['updated_at'];
    //$time += $row->temp_created_at - $row->temp_updated_at;
    $time += $row->created_at - $row->updated_at;



}
$average_time = $time / $num_of_solved1;
```

Comment: We are to assume these are all UNIX time stamps currently ?

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what do you have to assume .In my database i store the created_at and updated_at times using the date() function as i read it on the php manual

Comment: the php date function gives you a string representation of the date in wide variety of formats. If you you want to do math with time you have to use a unix timestamp, which is an integer. So is the data type of the "created_at" and "updated_at" fields "string" or "int"?

Comment: You're trying to do math with date/time? `$time += $row->created_at - $row->updated_at;`

Comment: $date= date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); this is how i store my date after that i bind this parameter  to created_at and update_at

Answer (score 0):

To do math with time you use unix timestamps which is basically the number of seconds since 1970, an integer.

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    $created = strtotime($row->created_at);
    $updated = strtotime($row->updated_at);
    $time += $created - $updated;
}
// $time at this point is in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL function [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for datetime subtraction:

```sql
SELECT 
    *,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `created_at`, `updated_at`) AS `diff`
FROM
    `ks`.`spots` 
WHERE
    solved = :solved
```

Then in your loop just sum your `diff` values:

```php
foreach ($results as $row) {
    # ...
    $time += $row['diff'];
}
```